# ZF2 Translator not provided in cronjob module

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, translation

In my cronjob module I am running some e-mail scripts with templates. Now I want to add some urls such as unsubscribe in the e-mail template but there seems to be a problem with routes with translated slugs.

For example, I have these routes and I want to include them both into my e-mail template.

```
      'newest' => array(
          'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
             'options' => array(
                'route' => '{newest}.html',
                     'defaults'   => array(
                     'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                     'action'     => 'newest',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

AND

```
        'contact' => array(
             'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                  'route' => 'contact.html',
                     'defaults'   => array(
                     'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                     'action'     => 'contact',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
```

The contact route is no problem and works fine! But when I am trying to include the newest route it goes wrong, an catch error check gives me back the message:

```
string(22) "No translator provided"
```

Well, I understand this point. Translation seems not to be provided as it's  based on locale in the Module.php of my Application module.

I would say, I should be able to force this Translator to use a translator? Like, using a parameter in my arguments while firing the route from the command line.

The code below is my current code, I guess I need to set the translator on top somehow?

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
        if (!$request instanceof ConsoleRequest)
            throw new \RuntimeException('Only access via console!');

        $country                       = $request->getParam('country');
        $sm                            = $this->serviceLocator;
        $http                          = $sm->get('HttpRouter');
        $render                        = $sm->get('ViewRenderer');
        $event                         = $this->getEvent()->setRouter($http);
        $config                        = $sm->get('config');
        $server_url                    = $config['server_url'][$country];
        try {
            var_dump($server_url . $this->url()->fromRoute('home/newest'));
            var_dump($server_url . $this->url()->fromRoute('home/contact'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
        exit;
```